# After-Effects CTI to selected keyframe

Tags: javascript, command, after-effects

I am new to After-Effects, and would like to add a function or a command to the application. I've checked the command list and am pretty sure this function does not already exist.

I would like to select a keyframe and then execute a function that will move the CTI to the selected keyframe. I would then map that function to a hotkey. Where do I start? Is it even possible?

Also, for clarity I am already familiar with how to cycle the CTI through existing keyframes already on the timeline. The answer I am searching for will, in one keystroke, move the CTI  directly to a keyframe I have selected without cycling through all the others.

I searched the apps existing command list and this command does not exist. I've searched online and there are only suggestions on how to assign commands that come baked into After Effects...but like I said this command does not exist.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.